# INSERT INTO without duplicates

Tags: mysql, insert, upsert

I want to do this

```
INSERT INTO AdminAccounts (Name) 
SELECT Name
FROM Matrix
```

But I don't want to create duplicates. ie, I ran this a few weeks ago and need to update the data.

Comment: This post should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218905/how-do-i-update-if-exists-insert-if-not-aka-upsert-or-merge-in-mysql Syntax : Insert ... On Duplicate Key Update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO AdminAccounts 
    (Name)
SELECT t1.name
  FROM Matrix t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT id
                    FROM AdminAccounts t2
                   WHERE t2.Name = t1.Name)
```

Answer (score 7):

This will insert new Name fields that were not previously in the Matrix table.

```
INSERT IGNORE
INTO AdminAccounts (Name) 
SELECT Name
FROM Matrix;
```

If you do not trust `INSERT IGNORE`, there is an alternative where you can manifest the new Name values before inserting them:

```
CREATE TABLE NewName SELECT Name FROM Matrix WHERE 1=2;
INSERT INTO NewName
    SELECT Name FROM AdminAccounts A
    LEFT JOIN Matrix B USING (Name)
    WHERE B.Name IS NULL;
INSERT INTO Matrix (Name) SELECT Name FROM NewNames;
```

The table `NewName` collects only those tables in `AdminAccounts` that are not in `Matrix` at present. This can give you a chance to look over the new Names. Afterwards, you can INSERT everything in `NewName` into Matrix.

Comment: Name is already set as the unique key. Also, this creates duplicates.

Comment: This cannot possibly create duplicates. `INSERT IGNORE` bars `INSERTs` from Duplicates by means of the PRIMARY KEY and other UNIQUE KEYs. Now, if you mean Duplicate Indexes, then, yes you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the 'name' field in 'AdminAccounts' a primary key or unique index, you may simply use

```
REPLACE INTO AdminAccounts (Name) 
SELECT Name
FROM Matrix
```

Thus, if a name doesn't exist in the table it will be inserted; if it exists, the old row is deleted and the new one is inserted.